# Diagonal elements of $A$ in $MAM=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given three square matrices $A, B$ and $M$ satisfing 
$$
MAM=B
$$
where $B^T=-B$ and $B_{ii}=0$ (diagonal elements are zeros); $M^T=M$ and $M$ is positive definite.

Is it possible to write an explicit formula for $A$'s diagonal elements (as a vector)? such as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{00}  \\
A_{11}\\
\cdots\\
A_{ii}
\end {bmatrix} =
$$
right now I'm sticking at $A=M^{-1} B M^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$MAM=B \implies A=M^{-1}BM^{-1}$$
$$M^TA^TM^T=B^T=-B$$

Hence $MA^TM=-B\implies A^T=-M^{-1}BM^{-1}$

$$A+A^T=0$$

Hence the diagonals of $A$ are $0$.

Comment: To my surprise. I just tested with an example, the result also shows that the diagonals are zeros.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask how you attach this problem so quickly? Do you have any insight to $A+A^T=0$ before making actual transformations?

Comment: well, I know that I have to take transpose and then I observe things on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in general. For instance, if $M$ and $B$ are all $0$, then no matter what $A$ is, the equation is fulfilled. In other words, it's impossible to exctract any information about $A$ at all from that equation alone.

If we knew more about $M$ and / or $B$, then we could get more information about $A$.

Comment: sorry for the missing information.  $M^T=M$ and $M\neq 0 $.

Comment: @whitegreen That changes nothing about my answer. We could still have $M = 0$.